# Outlook - Forward selected items as attachments macro - issue with forward symbol

Tags: vba, outlook

I found the below code from a very helpful post by user thommck. It forwards selected items as attachments in separate emails to a specified recipient.

When I use the code, the forward symbol does not appear on the email icon of the email I just forwarded. If I use the regular Outlook method for "Forward as Attachment," the symbol is added to the envelope icon in my viewing pane.

Any ideas on how to get this forward symbol to appear when using this code?

```
Sub ForwardSelectedItems()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("No item selected")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With objMsg
            .Attachments.Add objItem, olEmbeddeditem
            .Subject = "enter text"
            .To = "example@example.com"
            .Send
        End With
    Next

    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objMsg = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Forward](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865399.aspx) method of the MailItem class instead of creating a new mail item in the code:

```
 Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

should be replaced with:

```
 objItem.Foward()
```

Note, you need to clear the message body if you don't want to see the content of the attached item.

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate pressing a button with ExecuteMso.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419%28v=office.15%29.aspx

expression.ExecuteMso(idMso)

expression An expression that returns a CommandBars object.

To find the idMso, go through the process of adding a button to the Quick Access Toolbar or a ribbon. Once you find the control in the list, hover over it until the tooltip appears. The idMso is the name in brackets.

In this case it is ForwardAsAttachment